# Center ProgressBar and Image in XML android layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a loading screen for my android app.

It's working ok if I only use background image or ProgressBar, but when I try to center both elements in the middle of the screen I get that:

[image: layout_wrong]

So far my `activityy_main.xml` looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    tools:context="com.siconet.axa.MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/axa_logo" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="250px"
            android:layout_height="250px"
            android:indeterminate="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want to achieve is something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this layout

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    tools:context="com.siconet.axa.MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="250px"
            android:layout_height="250px"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminate="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `centerInParent` instead. Something like...

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >  // right here
```

But I think a better approach would be to just use a `LinearLayout`.Try the below layout...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent ="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/play"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="250px"
        android:layout_height="250px"
        android:background="@drawable/pause"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

</LinearLayout >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Take note of the different changes but this layout gives me the following ...

[image]

I don't see your `ImageView` in the second image so I centered them both. If you can explain where that should be then I can adjust this layout for that.

Comment: looks even worse... :( I HATE layouts xDDDD

Comment: You could try wrapping the whole thing in a `LinearLayout` and using `layout_gravity="center"`. To be honest, the two images look the same to me. If the point is to not show the webview until it is done then you should probably set the visibility to gone for that

Comment: in first image ProgressBar is in the corner of the image, in second is centered..... About `visibility` i set it of needed elements programatically, but that's not the problem. `webView` is a phonegap app and i have the nested layout `loadingPanel` to show progress bar in the top of the phoneGap app when needed...

Comment: Ah, yeah sorry, not sure how I missed that. Anyway, you can try with the updated layout in my answer. I haven't had a chance to test it but something similar should work.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a few adjustments and what it renders. Let me know if there is something different that you want.

Comment: `ImageView` and `ProgressBar` must be overlapped in same space with same center (the center of the screen), new solution just puts one element and after the oter one... thanks at all

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to your progressBar this line `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Try use Frame Layout instead of RelativeLayout in "loadingPanel"